# python - how to identify and remove rows unique values from a subset of duplicate rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe with rows that are almost duplicates, except for the value on one column.

```
event = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
subj = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
age = [22, 22, 56, 56, 32, 32, 48, 48, 19, 43]
sex = ['F', 'F','M',' M', 'M', 'M',' F',' F', 'F', 'M']
fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'mango', 'grape', 'mango', 'apple', 'mango']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(event, subj, age, sex, fruit)),
               columns =['event', 'subj', 'age', 'sex', 'fruit'])
```

Each subject is associated with two fruits (either with apple/orange or grape/mango). I'd like to omit some rows so that each subject is associated with only one fruit, and each with a different fruit.

This is what I want my final dataframe to look like:

```
event = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
subj = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
age = [22, 56, 32, 48, 19, 43]
sex = ['F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M']
fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'mango', 'apple', 'mango']

df_new = df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(event, subj, age, sex, fruit)),
               columns =['event', 'subj', 'age', 'sex', 'fruit'])
```

I have thousands of rows and don't know which rows are "almost duplicates". I've tried using .duplicated() based on a subset, but it only allows me to keep first or last, so different subjects end up with the same fruit (for example, subjects 1 and 2 with 'apple' and subjects 3 and 4 with 'grape').

I am new to pandas and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: to clarify some of the ambiguities in my question--within each event, the subjects should be unique. The subjects within the event should be associated with different fruits. There could be more than two subjects for each event, but each subject should not be associated with more than a single event (if subject 1 appeared in event 1, should not appear in other events, for example).

Comment: "Each with a different fruit" seems ambiguous, since there are only 4 fruits; what's the rule exactly ?

Comment: Within each event, the subjects should be unique. The subjects within the event should be associated with different fruits. Does that make sense?

Comment: Indeed this is more clear :) Please edit your question to mention that. Will the 2 entries for a given subject always be associated to the same event, and are there only 2 subjects for each event ?

Comment: Will do! There could be more than two subjects for each event, but the subjects should not be associated with more than a single event (if subject 1 appeared in event 1, should not appear in other events, for example).

Comment: If there are more than 2 subjects in the same event, do you have a guarantee that they aren't all associated with the same pair of fruits (in which case it would become impossible to assign a different fruit to each) ?

Comment: ah yeah that's a good point... there's no guarantee that they're all paired with a different fruit (even when there's only 2 subjects)....

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
df['check'] = (
    df.groupby(["event"])
    .apply(lambda x: x['fruit'].shift(1)==x['fruit'].shift(-1))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
df=df[df['check']==False].drop(['check'],axis=1)

print(df)
'''
   event  subj  age sex   fruit
0      1     1   22   F   apple
3      1     2   56   M  orange
4      2     3   32   M   grape
7      2     4   48   F   mango
8      3     5   19   F   apple
9      3     6   43   M   mango
'''
```